# Parsing local JSON file in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm new to Swift/IOS development.

Following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ih20QtEVCa0) tutorial I was able to fetch/display a local JSON file (actually a .txt file) by doing the following:

```
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "txt") else { return cell }
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

do{
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)

    guard let array = json as? [Any] else {return cell}

    for user in array {
        guard let userDict = user as? [String: Any] else  { return cell }
        guard let mName = userDict["name"] as? String else { return cell }
        print(mName)
    }

}catch{
    print(error)
}
```

This is working fine, it prints out all the names in my file.

---

Next, I wanted to populate this data in a `UICollectionView`. So I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2s60QwLrIs) tutorial. But in the tutorial he is fetching the JSON data from a api/link, as shown below:

```
import UIKit

typealias JSON = [String: Any]

class NetworkingService {

    static let shared = NetworkingService()
    private init() {}

    let session = URLSession.shared

    func getImgurs(success successBlock: @escaping (GetImgursResponse) -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/r/dogs") else { return }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.addValue("Client-ID 40dfbed2b6935ec", forHTTPHeaderField: "authorization")

        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, _, _) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? JSON else { return }
                print(json)
                let getImgursResponse = try GetImgursResponse(json: json)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    successBlock(getImgursResponse)
                }
            } catch {}
        }.resume()
    }

    func downloadImage(fromLink link: String, success successBlock: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
        session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            guard let data = data,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                successBlock(image)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

I first tried using the same logic as the first tutorial by changing the url as shown below:

```
import UIKit

typealias JSON = [String: Any]

class NetworkingService {

    static let shared = NetworkingService()
    private init() {}

    let session = URLSession.shared

    func getImgurs(success successBlock: @escaping (GetImgursResponse) -> Void) {
        //Changing the URL to local path
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "txt") else { return }
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)            

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.addValue("Client-ID 40dfbed2b6935ec", forHTTPHeaderField: "authorization")

        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, _, _) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? JSON else { return }
                print(json)
                let getImgursResponse = try GetImgursResponse(json: json)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    successBlock(getImgursResponse)
                }
            } catch {}
        }.resume()
    }

    func downloadImage(fromLink link: String, success successBlock: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
        session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            guard let data = data,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                successBlock(image)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

But then it returns at `guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? JSON else { return }`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hello @ClassA From API you getting image URL or ImageData ?

Comment: @BhaveshNayi I'm not interested in the data from the API, I'm interested in the data in the local JSON file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following function to populate local json data in `UICollectionView`

```
func getUsersList() -> [Any]{
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "txt") else { return [] }
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

    do{
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)

        guard let array = json as? [Any] else {return []}

        return array;

    }catch{
        print(error)
        return []
    }
}
```

After getting list from function then reload collection with same array like this:

```
var arrUsersLists : [Any] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.arrUsersLists = self.getUsersList()
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `Ambiguous reference to member 'collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)'` al line `self.collectionView.reloadData()`?

Comment: 'self.collectionView.reloadData()' this line for reload your collection view. you have to use your own collectionview object for reload.

Comment: Ok I have done that, so what should I do then in my `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {`? I have the following - my cell -> `let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell` then i set it like `cell.Name.text = Names[indexPath.row]`

Comment: if I print `print(arrUsersLists)` I get nothing `[]`

Comment: if arrUsersLists prints nothing so it means your self.getUsersList() function return empty array. You have to debug that function why it sends empty.


And in 'cellForItemAt' function you show write following code:

cell.Name.text = (arrUsersLists[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary).valueForKey("name") as? String

Comment: Ok I get the JSON data and I set `cell.Name.text = Names[indexPath.row]` but now I get this error  `Cannot assign value of type 'Any' to type 'String?'`

Comment: use as? String for casting value Any to String like:
cell.Name.text = Names[indexPath.row] as? String

Comment: I did then `cell.Name.text` doesn't return anything

Comment: Yes I have tried `print(arrUsersLists[indexPath.row] as? String)` it prints `nil nil` and I have tried `print(cell.Name.text)` with the same result

Comment: yes it will print nil. because your array contain NSDictionary. So you have to write like this 

print((arrUsersLists[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary).valueForKey("name") as? String)

Comment: Ok I got it working, so am I right in doing this then - `cell.Name.text = (arrUsersLists[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "name") as? String`

Comment: Very happy to hear that. great :). So I think now this answer deserve upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

```
do{
    if let jsonObject: AnyObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String: AnyObject] as AnyObject? {

        if let dict = jsonObject as? NSDictionary {
            if isDebuging {
                print(dict)
            }


        } else {
            print("not a dictionary")
        }
    }
    else {

        if isDebuging {
            print("Could not parse JSON: \(error!)")
        }


    }
}catch let  error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Can you please give a explanation what you are doing?

Comment: I have converted response data in JSON using JSONSerialization